# How enable google chrome browser to run local commands in Windows?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web, google-chrome-extension, plsql

I am using a web development tool called Oracle APEX 21.1 to create an app which will run on the web for some users and as desktop app for other users. The application runs in a browser in both cases. My problem is with the users that will use it as a desktop app. Sometimes I need to run a local file or run a specific program from the computer the user uses to run the app. The user is instructed to use google chrome to use the app. My question is, is there a setting of google chrome that I can set to allow my app to access local files or run Windows commands? Is there any other way i.e an add-on? If not, is there any other browser that can do the job? P.S: In my app, I can make use of JavaScript, JQuery, Oracle PL/SQL. Of course, a browser simple setting to set is the best option for me, if any.

Answer (score 0):

in browser you you have to do use "href" string like this :

```
window.location = "notes:///server/file";
```

"notes:///" program name

And "server/file" parameter for programe

Comment: I couldn't understand your answer. Kindly, give me an example.

Comment: What is **notes**? Does it refer to **notepad** app?